# Kings and Generals technology

Tags: animation

I'd like to make videos similar to a Youtube channel named Kings and Generals. Most of effects needed are object animation on a map.
If possible, there is a preference for Open Source software, for budget reason, plus the need of features are basic :D

Thank you!

[Sample video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nXforxAjuQo)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you seem to be looking for is a way to do fairly basic 2D animations. Blender, although technically a 3D animation tool, can also be used for 2D animations. You could also use GIMP to create raster graphics which could then be animated in Blender.  Blender and GIMP are both Open Source.

There's a basic tutorial which might interest you [on youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6vY7waCP0aA)

The tutorial includes the following steps

1. creation of 2D raster images in GIMP for use in the animation, i.e. separate images for each element of the animation
2. images are then imported into Blender onto a plain
3. the plain is then rotated 90 degrees
4. the camera is positioned and set to orthographic view
5. the images are then layered, scaled and positioned as required
6. then you can animate the different parts by using keyframes
7. finally the animation is rendered

I am no Blender expert, and questions about Blender are really beyond the scope of GDSE. However, there's a [Blender Stack Exchange](https://blender.stackexchange.com/) if you need help.  Blender questions are best asked there. However if you get stuck with GIMP, you can certainly ask here on GDSE.